# Fade out animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout

```
$("#btn-menu").click(function() {
    $("#btn-dropdown").slideToggle(400, function() {
        $("#btn-dropdown").animate({opacity: "0"})
            ? $("#btn-dropdown").animate({opacity: "100"}, "fast")
            : $("#btn-dropdown").animate({opacity: "0"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

I have a div that I want to change from opacity 0 to opacity 100. So that my div fades in. But for some reason above code won't work. It only works if I fade out (from 100 to 0)!

Comment: Is the element initially hidden, you can't fade in something that is already there? And I don't think the `css()` method animates anything, that would be `animate()`

Comment: yes I have `#btn-dropdown {opacity: 0}`

Comment: Avoid repeating `$("#btn-dropdown")`, because creating jQuery object wrappers is expensive. Save it in a variable instead: `var $btnDropdown = $("#btn-dropdown")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/):

```
$("#btn-dropdown").fadeToggle("fast");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part

```
$("#btn-dropdown").css({opacity: "0"}) ? ... : ...;
```

This *sets* the `opacity` of `#btn-dropdown` to 0. It doesn't *get* value of the element's opacity. Instead, what you want to do is this:

```
+$("#btn-dropdown").css('opacity') ? ... : ...;
```

This pulls the current `opacity` value (and uses the Unary Plus to ensure it is numeric (as `0` is equivalent to `false`)).

### Alternate Solution

An alternative solution would be to introduce some CSS:

```css
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
```

Then simply use [jQuery's `toggleClass` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to add or remove the class:

```
$("#btn-dropdown").slideToggle(400, function() {
    $("#btn-dropdown").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```